# How to see the full css code in data-styled="active" on a react website

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, styled-components

i went to this site which is a react website in there i tried to find the css file it showed me
`<style data-styled="active" data-styled-version="5.2.1"></style>` how can i copy all the css code in the `<style data-styled="active" data-styled-version="5.2.1"></style>`[image]

i tried to inspect and try to do all the experiments but it didn't show any css i was looking

Comment: Seems the site uses this library: https://styled-components.com/ As far as I can understand styles are defined in React components themselves